# Replacing old batten holder. Confusing wiring

Tags: wiring, lighting

I want to change an old broken batten holder but the wiring is really confusing . There are 3 red wires and 3 blacks. No green or white wire. I want to connect it to new 4 holes batten holder Can anybody help me with this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9DG4.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Some of those wires are powering the lamp, some of them might be going to and from the light switch, or powieing other light circuits etc.  I need to know how many of each colour go to each terminal on the existing batten holder, and any labels on the existign batten holder terminals. a photo of the new lamp holder showing the terminals would help too.  please edit your questuion to add that information

Comment: I am in Australia. I am not sure because there was no batten holder when I saw it in the first place.

Comment: there's a bunch of wires there and so far no way to determine the purpose of each one, what tools do you have for electrical work? I can identify the grounds but the others are hard to guess from a photo.